# What is the order of the run time for an algorithm with this desired output?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

There are N sets Ai to An each with string entries. The average size of a set is K.

For each Ai we wish to return a list (or a better data structure?) of N-1 sets excluding Ai ordered by how many elements the sets have in common with Ai?

Please don't be shy to give a detailed response with nice mathematical arguments...:)

Also is this a standard problem and can I read more about it somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicly you generate each result list element by performing an intersections of 2 sets. You have N-1 intersections in your result list element, that boils down to  N-1 * IntersectTime. For N list elements in the result this sums up to N(N-1) * IntersectTime. Afterwards you have to order N times N-1 sets, so just for ordering them you have O(N² log N).

IntersectTime depends on the implementation of the set, for a typical hashset this is for you O(k).

So finally we have O(N²k) + O(N² log N) = O(N² (k+log N)) =  (if we assume k > log N) O(N²k).

EDIT: when you would really implemnt it, it is good to know that when you intersect two sets, you can use the result for 2 of the result list elements, that means, that for the first you have to intersect A_1 with N-1, for A_2 with N-2 (intersection with A_1 was already done at for first element), for A_3 with N-3 other sets and finally for A_N with none. BUT this does not modify the big-O time, it just halfs the runtime.

Comment: How dependent is this answer on the specific algorithm you have chosen? For example is there any benefit to intersecting all the sets at the same time or doing some sort of guessing as we go along with the intersections?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: The Complexity is for the algorithm I gave, but it depends not on the order, so it does not matter if you first intersect everything and then sort all lists or create interchanging the lists and sort them. In my eyes there is not much room for improvement (Complexity wise), but as it holds with many other problems, proving that there is NO other faster approach is very hard (as you cant check ALL other theoretical algorithms). For pure theorists it is in P, that is enough ;-)

Comment: How did you determine O(N² log N) for ordering the output? It seems like this should be doable in O(N log N) at worst since you have to order the sets based on N integer numbers (# of common elements)

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Sure you sort a list with (N-1) elements in O(N log N). But you have N of such lists (for each Set you have a list with all intersections with all other lists). This adds up to O(N² log N).

Comment: Another optimization that doesn't change big-O complexity: instead of comparing every pair of sets, only compute $A_i \cap A_j$ and $A_i \cap A_k$ when your O(N*lg(N)) sorting algorithm instructs you to compare $A_j$ and $A_k$ for the $i$th result list. Run these two comparisons simultaneously: find a common element between $A_i$ and $A_j$, then a common element between $A_i$ and $A_k$, then $A_i$ and $A_j$ again (or do it in parallel threads). Interrupt as soon as you know which intersection is going to be bigger: e.g. when you have found $m+1$ common elements between $A_i$ and $A_j$, but...

Comment: ... you have found only $m-d$ common elements between $A_i$ and $A_k$ and there are only $d$ elements in $A_i$ that you haven't compared to $A_k$. Now store the running state of both intersection computation processes: for each, both which entries have been examined, and how many common entries were found. In this way you potentially store intermediate results for all N*(N-1)/2 pairs. When comparing two other sets, you can see if you need to do any more intersection computing (picking up where you left) or whether you can already derive the result from what is given by the stored results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt -

I believe you can boil the process down into:
O(N * (C + S))

Where N is the number of sets, C is the amount of time it takes to compare N-1 sets to set Ai, and S is the amount of time it takes to sort the N-1 sets.

The comparison is K items to K items N-1 times, so (N-1)K^2 time to compare

Sorting should take log(n - 1) time with an efficient algorithm
For simplicity, we can shorten N-1 into just N

So, the whole thing should run in O(N(NK^2 + log(N)))

You should take this with a grain of salt, I haven't done anything with algorithms for quite a while.  There may also be a more efficient way to compare the sets.